# How to receive data back after sending a html form to flask app?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I have a HTML site which contains a signup form and login form, the signup and login work as intended in terms of the database - the data is sent to flask and flask updates the database after verifying the data.

In terms of the login page I have used flask to check if the data sent by the form matches the database, it checks the database using SQL and currently I just have flask returning a page which says 'username and password correct' however I'd like to (correct me if there is a better way please) return a bool value e.g. validLogin as True but I'm not sure how to receive and process this on the HTML/javascript side.

I searched around and saw people returned using a dictionary in flask through a built in package known as jsonify but I'm not sure how to 'catch' this data.
-> if my data is correct I want to be able to return something like: `{"validLogin:" : True}` then catch this using javascript to allow the user to be logged in.

Comment: Are you using Flask-Login by any chance?

Comment: No I'm not, would I be able to implement it alongside my sqlite3 database?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I searched around and saw people returned using a dictionary in flask through a built in package known as jsonify but I'm not sure how to 'catch' this data. -> if my data is correct I want to be able to return something like: {"validLogin:" : True} then catch this using javascript to allow the user to be logged in." This question has **nothing to do with** either Python or Flask. It's a question about what Javascript needs to be in the page in order to use that response; therefore, it's a Javascript question.

Comment: I believe this is a question regarding Python and Flask as I do not believe the method I have described is correct. It was just my idea of what I think could work and I think the correct answer would require the use of Flask + Python. I do appreciate any help.

Answer (score -1):

you can do this by jinja2:

```py
# in your python file

from flask import reander_template

#............

@app.route("/...", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def check():
    #check something...
    validLogin=True
    return render_template("example.html", validLogin=validlogin)
```

and

```html
# in /templates/example.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    {% if validLogin %}
      <p>login is valid</p>
    {% else %}
      <p>login is not valid</p>
    {% endif %}
  </body>
</html>
```